# How to call sequential methods?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am using mechanize and blind testing pages and sending GET requests to urls and see if I get content back or not.    Wanted to know the ruby approach to doing this. **Basically if option A doesn't work, do option B**.

This is something along the lines that I am doing now (this feels like a conditional):

```
blind_test(pagethatdoesnotexist) || blind_test(pagethatdoesexist)
# option A^^^^^^^                        option B^^^^^^^^^
```

Here's another potential method:

```
blind_test(pagethatdoesexist) if blind_test(pagethatdoesnotexist).nil?
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You seem to already know at least two mechanisms to do what you want.

Comment: wanted to make sure.  I was confused that I was getting true returned sometimes...